# React <video/> flickers and restarts on parent rerender

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to use a video in a component, but whenever a parent is rerendered (unavoidable in this situation, due to a lot of complex functionality) the video tag flashes/flickers and restarts. I have tried using useMemo and seperating into a seperate component and implementing React.memo(), shouldComponentUpdate(), and extending PureComponent (although i recognize its not recommended to use these to reliably prevent a rerender in the docs). I am thinking it some problem with the functionality of the html video player or something right now because i tried logging on the components rerender and am seeing the behaviour without any log to the console. In this [visual example](https://gyazo.com/ac72c4a216f713950510737dc4310553) you can see on the top the component with this behaviour, and on the bottom another component (That has almost the same code) with a gif that uses image instead of video

```
let url = "url here"

const renderVideo = useMemo(
            () => (
                <video
                    src={url}
                    controls
                    muted={true}
                    autoPlay
                    height="100%"
                    width="100%"
                    style={{
                        borderRadius: "0.25rem",
                    }}
                />
            ),
            [url, keepScale, fit]
        );

        return (
            <Widget 
                {...props}
                editorContent={<EditorContent />}
                >
                {renderVideo}
               
            </Widget>
        );
```

that should be the relevent code. This component is pretty simple, complex functionality is implemented in the Widget component you can see

Comment: Your parent component forces your child component to re-render, your fix will most likely be in the parent component and you need to figure out what's causing the re-render

Comment: @SeanW keepScale and fit are properties that i removed from the code i provided for simplification, just forgot to remove from the dep array. It makes no difference.

Comment: @gandharvgarg The parent rerendering is unavoidable, It is needed for several behaviors. The component below with a gif does not have this issue when the parent rerenders, and maintains its appearance with no flickering

Comment: hmm looks like onMouseOver the video resets... try giving a onMouseOver event handler on <video>, onMouseOver={e => {}}

Comment: @gandharvgarg  Adding the handler doesnt make a difference

Comment: I suspect that one or more of your deps (url, keepScale, or fit) are changing (or getting redefined - url is a let for some reason) -  causing re-rendering.   To test this move the video to its own component and pass only the url as a prop - put the url as a string don't use the variable for the test.